# Differentiating between functions with same name from different header files

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a 2D vector class which contains a function to round x and y of the vector to the nearest int. to do this I thought I could use the `<math.h>` `round()` but the name of my Vector2 function is `Vector2.round()`, this causes an error because the computer thinks I'm giving too many arguments (1) because my `Vector2.round()` function isn't meant to take any arguments, I though putting `math::round()` instead of `round()` might work but I guess the math library doesn't use a namespace because it didn't work, how can I tell the computer that I'm trying to access the `<math.h>` method as opposed to the one I wrote.

Comment: have you tried using `::round()` instead of `math::round()`

Comment: Please provide [mcve] of code you are trying to compile. It's hard to deduce what `round()` means what. I can suggest to use `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` and then you can use `std::round` to refer to standard library `round()`. Calling your own function may still be ambiguous for the compiler if your own function is in global namespace, called `round` and has single `double` argument tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There Are Two Approaches:

1. Using `::round()` instead of `math::round()`. This Approach is however compiler dependent and as cited [here](https://azrael.digipen.edu/%7Emmead/www/Courses/CS270/Namespaces-math.h.html) works well only for Microsoft Or GNU Compiler.
2. Using `cmath` library. Supports the same functions as `math.h` but its functions are present in `std` namespace allowing you to use `std::round()` as cited [here](https://qr.ae/pvsq0P)

Comment: I believe the recommendation is to use <cmath> (without .h) instead

Comment: Realised that i wrote `cmath.h` instead of `cmath`...... Thanks For Notifying @codeling